# Python string equality always returns false

Tags: python, string, comparison, equals

I've got a problem with my Python code. For some reason a comparison of two strings is always returning `False`.

```
def checkChanged(checkURL, currentMessage):
  tempMessage = urllib.urlopen(checkURL)
  tempMessage = tempMessage.read()
  print (tempMessage + ". " + currentMessage + ".")
  if (str(tempMessage) == str(currentMessage)):
    print ("equal")
    return False
  else:
    print ("not equal")
    return True
```

(**Assume indentation is correct. I had to re-format when inserting here**)

The problem I think is the `if` statement, I have tried many variations where both string weren't enclosed by the `str()`, I have also tried `is` instead of `==` but it is `False`. I have printed both values on the line before just to check and they are infact equal. Am I missing something?

Comment: What does `print repr(tempMessage), repr(currentMessage)` print? The strings most likely contain non-printable characters that are not immediately obvious when printing the contents, but `repr()` will make the difference clear.

Comment: Can you give an example of inputs that produce the problem?

Comment: Thanks Martijn you were right. I used the strip function and it now works. Must have been those non-printables ;)